# Wifi And Touchpad Not Working On Linux Mint 18.2 , Manjaro, Debian and Ubuntu 17.04 on Acer Aspire ES 15 521

Tags: ubuntu, debian, linux-mint, touchpad, manjaro

In **Manjaro**, wifi worked but in **linux mint**, **Debian** and **ubuntu** both wifi and my **precision** touchpad didn't work. I tried restarting the wifi but displayed disconnected. I checked the info but it said **hard blocked**. I entered code for it searching from internet but didn't work. Please help.
I heard that I had to wait for the next version of Ubuntu to be compatible with my touch pad.
My friend had that problem too in his laptop (another model) but it worked fine when next version of Ubuntu was launched.
Product: **Acer Aspire ES15 ES1-521-880K**

Comment: If you were to connect an external mouse to the computer, does the external mouse work?

Comment: Yes, the pointer moved when external USB mouse was added.

Comment: touchpad worked by changing the touchpad from 'advanced' to 'basic' in boot menu.

Comment: but wifi is **hard blocked**!!

Comment: Run `lspci | grep -i wireless` in a terminal and post the output here please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the windows had blocked the hardware.
I turned off windows 10 properly by going in the power menu and disabling the fast boot.
Then I installed Linux mint 18.2
but wifi was still not working. So I turned of bluetooth and joined a charger and wifi worked. (The main point is you have to alter the power supply. Either you have to charge or you've to restart.)
The I tried
**lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net** on terminal
then I turned on bluetooth ( and wifi disconnected)
then
**sudo modprobe -r ath9k** on terminal. (you have to replace **ath9k** with your kernal driver given by the 1st code)
then my wifi and bluetooth worked fine.
(if yours doesn't work then restart)
Source:https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=185809#p962380